# Using Boost.Process to capture output from exe for testing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use Boost.Process to build a test for the output of a test.exe.

```
std::string exe = "test.exe";

boost::asio::io_service ios;
boost::process::async_pipe ap(ios);
boost::process::opstream stream
boost::process::child sim(exe, boost::process::std_out > ap, boost::process::std_in < stream);

std::vector<char> buf;
boost::asio::async_read(ap, boost::asio::buffer(buf), [](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t size) {});

ios.run();

stream << "Test";
```

If I run the above code the buf is empty.  What is the easiest way to make buf contain "Test". For my tests I need to send in some strings to cin and capture the resulting cout.

This is my simple test program:

```
int main() {
    std::string line;
    while (std::cin) {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::cout << line;
    }
}
```